# Where do I put META-INF in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, kundera

I'm using the Kundera tutorial at https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Getting-Started-in-5-minutes. Eclipse does not find it when I create a folder META-INF at the project root and place persistence.xml in it.

I did a quick search and there was no real solution posted.

There is no valid reason why a simple file path should be difficult to configure. I'm looking for a simple answer to what should be a simple issue.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It shouldn't be at the project root, but directly under the source folder.

At runtime, the persistence.xml file is searched in the classpath, under META-INF. So if you want the META-INF folder to be put at the top of the compiled package tree, you need to put it at the top of the source tree. Eclipse copies every non-Java file to its output directory (bin, by default), respecting the package/folder hierarchy.

Comment: Works for NetBeans (7.1) too: `/<project>/src/META-INF`

Comment: @craig The same works in Eclipse too:  `/<project>/src/META-INF`

Comment: I put it under `src`, `src/main`, `src/main/resources` but nothing, the folder is not copied when I debug the application in the `bin` directory.

Comment: Well, I had to put it under `src/main/java`. Ugly but effective.

Answer (score 29):

Basically it has to be in your classpath(under `/META-INF/`). You can manually enable it in eclipse by configuring properties. If your project is maven based, then it should be automatically picked from `/src/main/resources/META-INF/` folder (*provided entities are under the same hood*).

Comment: The same default path (`/src/main/resources/META-INF/`) is used in [Gradle](http://gradle.org) based projects.

Comment: Putting the MANIFEST.MF file in /src/main/resources/META-INF/, didn't work for me, in my Gradle project.(Gradle Version 6.8.3).

Answer (score 13):

It should be under `src/main/resources` directory,

The full path will be `/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

After creating the META-INF folder under resources directory and having a persistence.xml file loads the entityMangerFactory bean properly,

```
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
```

The above line reads the path correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse, right-click on 'src' folder, choose 'Build Path', then 'Use as Source Folder'

Comment: AWW YEHAH ! Thank you it worked for me after 2 days of unbarbecueing