# JPA configuration - persistence.xml is automatically created under src/main/java instead of src/main/resource

Tags: eclipse, maven, jpa, spring-tool-suite, jpa-2.1

I am using Maven 3.3.9 and created a Maven Web Project in **Spring tool suite and using Eclipse.**

Recently I went through a Tutorial for configuring JPA with maven project.

[Tutorial showing JPA configuration](http://www.javabeat.net/eclipselink-jpa-installation-configuration/)

I successfully configured Database connection using EclipseLink2.5

[image: META-INF created under src\main\java]

**PROBLEM I AM FACING IS**
After I click ok followed by configuring JPA 2.1 using project Facet properties. Persistence.xml is created automatically under **META-INF** of **src/main/java** **instead of** **src/main/resource** location.

Is this correct ??

I had already researched a lot on this, in every blog it is mentioned that META-INF should be placed under src/main/java and not under  src/main/resource.

**Then why is it every time I create a Maven project and configure JPA from Project Facet, Its ends up automatically creation under src/main/java.**

please refer my screenshot.

So should I remove this folder META-INF/Persistence.xml from src/main/java and paste it manually under  src/main/resource.

Comment: those are the same folder, just move META-INF to `java/main/resources`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always move META-INF to src/main/resources. Everything is going to be happier with things configured that way.

[Where do I put META-INF in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998360/where-do-i-put-meta-inf-in-eclipse).