# Java Hibernate Issue: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named BookStoreWebsite

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I know this question has been out there for a while but I tried about 10 different solutions and nothing worked. I'm new to Hibernate and Maven, so I'm a bit lost.

I've checked if persistence is inside Meta-inf,
added provider tag under persistence unit,
checked libraries
and so on...

[image]

```
import com.bookstore.entity.Users;

public class UsersTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Users user1 = new Users();
        user1.setEmail("pablo.the.souza@gmail.com");
        user1.setFullName("Pablo Souza");
        user1.setPassword("123456");
        
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("BookStoreWebsite");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        
        entityManager.persist(user1);
        
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
        
        System.out.println("A users object was persisted");
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="BookStoreWebsite">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstore" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    
</persistence>
```

Comment: Provide your github link code

Comment: Read here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998360/where-do-i-put-meta-inf-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Hibernate core dependency from:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0.Alpha5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <type>pom</type>  
</dependency>
```

to this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.12.Final</version>  
</dependency>
```

And it works. Not sure why unfortunately.